# Office Open XML文書で箇条書き文、番号付き文を見分ける方法が知りたい

Tags: xml, document

Office Open XMLのdocument.xmlにおいて、<w:p>要素で括られた段落が箇条書文、又は番号付文かどうかを判断したいです。
現状は、下記の方法により箇条書文、又は番号付文を判断しようとしています。

以下、document.xml、style.xml、numbering.xmlの抜粋です。

document.xml：

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="xxx" />
                <w:numPr>
                    <w:numId w:val="yyy" />
                </w:numPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr/>
                <w:t>この段落の文字列</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

style:xml：

```
<w:style w:styleId="xxx">
     <w:name />
    <w:basedOn />
    <w:next />
    <w:link />
    <w:uiPriority />
    <w:qFormat />
    <w:rsid />
    <w:pPr />
    <w:rPr />
        <w:rFonts />
        <w:sz />
        <w:szCs />
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

numbering.xml：

```
<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="zzz">
    <w:lvl>
        <w:numFmt w:val="decimal" />又は<w:numFmt w:val="bullet" />
    </w:lvl>
</w:abstractNum>

<w:num w:numId="yyy">
        <w:abstractNumId w:val="zzz" />
</w:num>
```

概略的な段落スタイルについては、document.xmlの<w:pStyle w:val="**xxx**" />の**xxx**部分が、style.xmlの<w:style w:styleId=**"xxx**">の**xxx**部分と関連付けられているようですが、ここには箇条書や番号付の情報は含まれていないようでした。

箇条書や番号付の情報は、document.xmlの<w:numId w:val="**yyy**" />の**yyy**部分が、numbering.xmlの<w:num w:numId="**yyy**">の**yyy**部分と関連付けられ、この<w:num>要素で括られた<w:abstractNumId w:val="**zzz**" />の**zzz**部分が同じnumbering.xmlの<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="**zzz**">の**zzz**部分にリンクし、<w:abstractNum>要素で括られた情報の中の<w:numFmt w:val="**decimal**" />又は<w:numFmt w:val="**bullet**" />で"**decimal**"（番号付文）か"**bullet**"（箇条書文）を判断できないかと考えています。

関連付ける要素や属性が不明なので、サンプルのWordファイルを作成して、そのOOXMLを見ながら上記の判断に辿り着きましたが、このあたりをご存知の方がみえましたら、是非ともご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺りが参考になるかもしれません。 https://www.antenna.co.jp/office/publication/part_wordprocessingml/chapter_numbering.html

Comment: ありがとうございました。
教えていただいたサイトに関連付ける要素や属性の記述がありました。
いくつかサンプルを作成して確認してみたいと思います。
今後とも、よろしくお願いいたします。